# opencv::Mat, get pixel value from the raw data?

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I have an image, as a `cv::Mat`. I am getting the raw data from this, with:

```
uchar* data = (uchar *)pImg.data;
```

I need to pass this data to a function, then cycle through each pixel of the image. I would have done:

```
for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; ++j)
        {
            //pixel = cv::Point(i,j);
        }
    }
```

What is the equivalent of this, using the `uchar*` data?

Comment: Depends on the pixel type of `pImg`. What is the pixel type?

Comment: I actually need to do two Mats, a `uchar` and an  int.

Answer (score 4):

It is pretty easy but you need to remember one thing, this `image.elemSize()` indicates how many bytes there are per pixel (this function is taken from OpenCV mat). So this loop will look little bit different for different image formats. There is a example inside the loop

```
   for (auto i = 0; i < image.rows * image.cols; i+=image.elemSize())
   {
      //for CV_8UC1  
      //auto pixel = *(image.data + i)

      //for RGB as CV_8UC3 
      auto r = *(image.data + i)
      auto g = *(image.data + i + 1)
      auto b = *(image.data + i + 2)
   }
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking that this equates to: ( for CV_8UC1)

`data[x * step + y * channels]`

Answer (score 3):

The correct pixel value can be accessed from the raw data provided the following parameters are known:

- X coordinate of pixel ( column number )
- Y coordinate of pixel ( row number )
- Image depth (actual data type of a single pixel i.e. `uchar`, `ushort`, `float` etc)
- Number of channels of the image
- Image step in bytes

Given the above information, the pixel can be accessed as follows (for `CV_8UC3` type):

```
uchar* data = (uchar *)pImg.data;
for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; ++j)
    {
        uchar b = data[i * pImg.step + pImg.channels() * j + 0];
        uchar g = data[i * pImg.step + pImg.channels() * j + 1];
        uchar r = data[i * pImg.step + pImg.channels() * j + 2];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am still having problems. The following will crash:

`int* tri = new int[width * height];`

`for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
 {
  for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
  {
  
   tri[i * step + j * channels] = 0; 

  }
 }`

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: To be more specific, i am running this:

`int* tData = new int[trimap.cols * trimap.rows];` 


`for (auto i = 0; i < trimap.rows * trimap.cols; i += trimap.elemSize())
 {
  //for CV_8UC1  
  auto pixel = *(trimap.data + i);
  tData[i] = pixel; 

 }`



Then accessing the data with:  `tData [i * step + j * channel` will crash

Comment: Ah, I needed to cvt to gray before i stored the step and channels. Runs fine. thanks again.

Comment: @anti.. The `step` value for `uchar` is not applicable to `int`. If `tri` is just a simple array, its `step` will be equal to `width`. In other words, the step has to be divided by the size of data type before accessing an element.